# How to build FFTW in Ubuntu?

Tags: c, kinect, gesture

I have been working on Gesture recognition project. I use XKin gesture recogntion  library https://github.com/fpeder/XKin. To compile Xkin i had to install fftw (http://www.fftw.org/download.html) I build fftw successfully with

```
./configure  
make  
make install
```

But when i build Xkin i got this Error

`/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libfftw3.a(lt4-problem.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against`.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC

/usr/local/lib/libfftw3.a: error adding symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [lib/posture/libposture.so] Error 1

make[1]: *** [lib/posture/CMakeFiles/posture.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2`

Comment: Why didn't you just `apt-get install libfftw3-dev`?

Comment: I did but nothing has changed i still got the same error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

do this

`./configure --enable-shared

  sudo make CFLAGS=-fPIC

  sudo make install`

This will solve your problem.